# How to create an address variable in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, popsql

I'm creating a table to catalogue information about customers at a car dealership.
One of the variables is going to catalogue is a customer's address.
What variable type in SQL could I use to store the address with a mix of words & numbers?

Comment: It is likely that you even should split the parts of an address into several columns. That depends on your exact needs/use case. And that's problem with such "Help me make my data model" questions is that they're typically too broad for SO, unless it is a specific question about a specific design decision. They would require detailed knowledge about what should be modeled in the real world where even a small scope typically raises a lot of questions during the design process. And SO is designed as a Q & A platform and not for such interactive processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for datatype of Address variable then Varchar would be the best choice since you can have digits, characters and special characters in it.
For ex:

```
George H. Washington
1234 Main Street, Apartment 101
Manvel, Texas, USA 77578
```

Address like above can have commas and number and hypen in it.

VARCHAR(255) would work but if you expect to address to be more than 255 then you can specify more like VARCHAR(500).

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly!